# Delay this CSS fade in

Tags: html, css

Using this link, http://jsfiddle.net/UtnHS/ I want to make the image fade in quickly after 5 seconds. So far, changing the opacity properties only makes a difference in the appearance whilst fading in. I simply want to delay the fade in all together and have it load completely after 5 seconds. Example: try changing the `2s` to `20s` and it loads in slowly. I want it to load quickly (after 5 seconds). I essentially want there to be white space for 5 seconds, then I want the picture to load completely.

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/images/bird-photography.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using transition delay option, changing this `transition: opacity 2s;` to:

```
transition: opacity 2s 5s;
```

where the `2s` represents the duration of transition, the `5s` at the end indicates the delay time before playing the transition.

You can also write it using the "long-hand" way, on its own line like this:

```
transition-delay: 5s;
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/9jeb56a6/)

```css
img {
  opacity: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s 5s;  /* Firefox 4 */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transition: opacity 2s 5s;
  transition: opacity 2s 5s;
}
```

```html
<img onload="this.style.opacity='1';" src="http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/images/bird-photography.jpg" />
```

Resources:

- [MDN: transition-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/)
- [CSS-Tricks: transition-delay-delays](https://css-tricks.com/transition-delay-delays/)

Comment: Awesome. It worked completley. Thank you @Mi-Creativity. Stack says I have to wait 9 more minutes before choosing your answer! Update ahead. Thanks